# Generating a Random Selection from Multiple Sections in a Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, libreoffice-calc

I've been wanting to do like the creator of Aeon of Strife did to Starcraft (or Defense of the Ancients to Warcraft III) by jerry-rigging elements of Dungeons and Dragons 5th Edition into a more Rogue-like system. I've recorded all the class features for the system in a spreadsheet. I'm looking for a solution that will pick, in sequence: a section of the spreadsheet with a defined row and column limit, a row within that section, a column within that row, then print what's in that cell. I'm unaware of how different Excel and LibreOffice Calc are for syntax and mathematic functionality, I'm using LibreOffice, if you know how to solve my issue in Excel I'd appreciate that as well.

I haven't really tried to solve this issue, as I don't personally know how to use the mathematic functions of spreadsheets.

Comment: In LibreOffice Calc, open the Function Wizard (the `fx` button) and select the Mathematical category. Look at the various random functions, then research online how to use them. After that, if you still need help, edit the question to explain what you've tried so far, with links to relevant documentation.

Comment: Thanks, Jim! I'll be sure to do that.